# I am getting error in my JEE socket project SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, maven, sockets

When I try to run my server code ..

**Server code**

```
package Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.mina.core.service.IoAcceptor;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IdleStatus;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.textline.TextLineCodecFactory;
import org.apache.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter;
import org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor;

public class MinaTimeServer
{

    private static final int PORT = 1865;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
        acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "logger", new LoggingFilter() );
        acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
        acceptor.setHandler( new TimeServerHandler() );
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize( 2048 );
        acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime( IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10 );
        acceptor.bind( new InetSocketAddress(PORT) );
    }
}

**Server Handler Code**

package Socket;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.mina.core.session.IdleStatus;
import org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession;

public class TimeServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter   
{

@Override
public void exceptionCaught( IoSession session, Throwable cause ) throws Exception
{
    cause.printStackTrace();
}
@Override
public void messageReceived( IoSession session, Object message ) throws Exception
{
    String str = message.toString();
    System.out.println(str);
    if( str.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("quit") ) {
        session.close();
        return;
    }
    Date date = new Date();
    session.write( "Thank you client"+date.toString() );
    System.out.println("Message written...");
}
@Override
public void sessionIdle( IoSession session, IdleStatus status ) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( "IDLE " + session.getIdleCount( status ));
}
}
```

**My Maven pom xml file exist**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
<artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>

<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But still server is in running state and when Client is connected with  Server is repeatedly printing IDLE 1, IDLE 2,IDLE 3 , IDLE 4 ....
instead of printing message .

Comment: You miss the slf4j.jar in your classpath

Comment: I already have the dependency for that . Can you please tell me what will be the exact dependency for that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code will output:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

that's to say the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate **SLF4J** binding could be found on the class path. 
    ---- **reference** from [SLF4J warning or error messages and their meanings](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)

So an alternative solution add this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```